# Acumatica - copy files from Appointments to invoice and Memos

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I am trying to move files that are attached to the Appointments page(FS300200) to Invoice and memos page(AR301000). This is after or during the Run Appointment Billing Action.

The File Maintenace header data is in the SQL table UploadFile.

It doesn't look like the file is saved inside UploadFile, where is the file saved?

What DACs should I populate to copy the file over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied below from my method which pushes files from an Opportunity to a Service Order.  Also I adapted in order to act on ARInvoice & Service Order.  You may adapt it for your situation.  In graph **CreateInvoiceBase**, there is a method named **CreateInvoices**.  See if you can use the injection routine below, and extend/override CreateInvoices, or a related method in that graph.

```
PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<ARInvoiceEntry>((graph) =>
{
  graph.RowInserted.AddHandler<ARInvoice>((sender, e) =>
  {
  ARInvoice arInvoice = e.Row as ARInvoice;
    foreach(UploadFile file in PXSelectJoin <UploadFile,
    InnerJoin<NoteDoc, On<NoteDoc.fileID, Equal<UploadFile.fileID>>,
    InnerJoin<FSAppointment, On<FSAppointment.noteID, Equal<NoteDoc.noteID>>>>,
    Where<FSAppointment.refNbr,Equal<Current<FSAppointment.refNbr>>,
    And<FSAppointment.srvOrdType,Equal<Current<FSAppointment.srvOrdType>>.Select(Base))
    { 
      PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(sender, arInvoice, file.FileID.Value);
    }
 });
});
```